# linq/ef/c# - return a group of records

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am looking to return with linq all PersonID's that are at a certain stage. My example data set is -

```
ID  DateCreated Stage PersonID
1   1/1/2012    A    101   
2   1/1/2012    A    102
3   1/1/2012    A    103
4   1/1/2012    A    104
5   2/1/2012    B    101
6   3/1/2012    B    102
7   3/1/2012    B    103
8   3/1/2012    C    101
9   4/1/2012    C    102
10  5/1/2012    C    103
11  5/1/2012    D    101
```

So if i wanted to return all those at stage c i would get only PersonID's 102,103


Any ideas?

Comment: Any particular reason item whit `PersonID = 101` would not be returned for `Where(p => p.Stage=="C")` or it just mistake in data/expectations?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov He only wants the person ID's for the people who are currently AT stage C and exclude those who are not yet there or have already passed it.

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerable<int> personIds = DbContext.Table
    .GroupBy(record => record.PersonID)
    .Where(group => group.Last().Stage == "c")
    .Select(group => group.Key)
```

This way if a person, like 101 has advanced past stage c then will not be returned because their last stage is D. 104 would also not be returned because he has not yet reached stage C. To visualize it, it would look something like this. Last stage is in brackets.

```
Group: 101 - A, B, C, [D]
Group: 102 - A, B, [C]
Group: 103 - A, B, [C]
Group: 104 - [A]
```

Comment: yes the where would bring back all those who have a record stage c, however I only want to return those at a stage c. Imagine stage is a process a-b-c-d I only want to show those at stage c. A where would bring back all those who have a record of stage c.

Comment: That looks good to me, will try this out tomorrow and let you know how I get on.

Comment: so I tried this out and got the error - linq to entities does not recognize the method last. I also tried DbContext.Table.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateCreated)
    .GroupBy(record => record.PersonID)
    .Where(group => group.FirstOrDefault().Stage == "c")
    .Select(group => group.Key)       but no returns no records at all

Answer (score 1):

So I finally got it working here is the solution -

```
 var query = DbContext.Table
                .GroupBy(p => p.PersonID)
                .Select(grp =>  grp.OrderByDescending(
                     d => d.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault()
                ).Where(a => a.Stage =="C");
```

Thanks for your help @Despertar.